# Formio TypeError: Cannot set property navigator of #<Object> which has only a getter

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start, formio

I'm trying to build `formio` manually using `npm`, `node`, `mongodb` as given in the instructions.

I have started the `mongodb server`, used `npm install` to install required packages, then encountered this error on trying npm start.[Screenshot of the error on npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS0JN.png) If anyone knows how to resolve these please let me know

tried `npm` start to start "formio" cloned from git after installing all packages. it keeps returning

```
Formio TypeError: Cannot set property navigator of #<Object> which has only a getter error
```

Answer (score 0):

It was due to node version mismatch, had to downgrade to node:lts-alpine3.10 and it worked well. install nvm to manage node versions and downgrade to any lts versions